# Div with class and id, some height is overwritten

Tags: css, class, html

I am using this div:

```
<div id="container" class="large">
```

In my CSS the ID is assigned a default height like this:

```
#container {height: 500px}
```

In this one case I'd like the div to be larger, but this would overwrite the class.

```
.large{height: 560px}
```

I don't what to make a *class small* and a *class large*...
 **How can I do this ?**
Append to the class and only effecting this div to make it bigger !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just combine the selectors:

```
#container.large { height : 560px; };
```

This increases the specificity of the selector, since there's an `id` *and* a `class`, without creating future problems using `!important`.

To explain specificity for CSS, it's worth reading these articles:

- [CSS Specificity: Things you Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).
- [Molly Holzschlag's 'CSS 2.1 Specificty Clarified'](http://www.molly.com/2005/10/06/css2-and-css21-specificity-clarified/).
- [CSS Specificty Calculator, from suzyit.com](http://www.suzyit.com/tools/specificity.php).

Answer (score 2):

Use a higher specificity for the container that is meant to be longer than the default.

```
#container.large { height: 560px }
```

Will apply a 560px height to an element with ID 'container' and class name 'large'.

An ID selector will by default have higher specificity over a class selector no matter where it appears in the document, since an ID can only appear once in a document (and is thus very specific). In this case we're expanding on our specific ID selector with a class name, being more specific than just having an ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
.large{height: 560px !important}
```

That will override the style set by `#container`.

Comment: why the ID overwrite the container... it make no sense since it can be attach a lot of class an only one ID !... it should apply id the class !

Comment: Because `id` is more specific as a selector than a `class`, therefore the rendering engine 'scores' it higher, making it more important.